# Can the last non-zero term in the central series of an indecomposable nilpotent Lie algebra be smaller than the center?

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be an indecomposable nilpotent Lie algebra (finite dimensional and over $\mathbb{C}$). Is it possible for the last non-zero term of the central series to be strictly smaller than the center?

For context, as shown in [The center of a nilpotent Lie algebra intersects each ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658670/the-center-of-a-nilpotent-lie-algebra-intersects-each-ideal/) any non-trivial ideal will intersect non-trivially with the center. But in [If L is nilpotent then $K\cap L^n \not=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658629/if-l-is-nilpotent-then-k-cap-ln-not-0/) it is shown that it is possible to have a non-trivial ideal which intersects the last non-zero term of the central series trivially. However, the example given is decomposable, and the answerer himself wonders in a comment whether it is also possible with an indecomposable Lie algebra.
Also note that a Lie algebra has the property that any non-trivial ideal has non-trivial intersection with the last non-zero term of the central series iff that term coincides with the center.

Comment: Where can I find a proof for your last statement: "Also note that a Lie algebra has the property that any non-trivial ideal has non-trivial intersection with the last non-zero term of the central series iff that term coincides with the center."?

Comment: @Ronald It is fairly straightforward to show once you know that this last non-zero term is contained in the center (consider what happens if it is smaller than the center and use this to construct an ideal which has trivial intersection with it).

Comment: So if the algebra is nilpotent, then the center intersects the last non-zero term  (actually  the last non-zero term is central). Then the  last non-zero term is exactly the center?

Comment: @Ronald Actually, I think the way I stated it is not correct (any simple Lie algebra is a counter example). But once the algebra is nilpotent, then if the last non-zero term is strictly smaller than the center, we can just take a complement of it inside the center to get something non-trivial intersection it trivially).

Comment: Any subspace of the center is an abelian ideal (this you really should be able to show directly).

Comment: You are right,, sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Here is an example of an indecomposable $7$-dimensional $5$-step nilpotent Lie algebra $L$, with basis $(x_1,\ldots ,x_7)$ and brackets
$$
[x_1,x_2]=x_3,\,[x_1,x_3]=x_4,\,[x_1,x_4]=x_6,\,[x_1,x_6]=x_7,\,[x_2,x_3]=x_5,
$$
where we have $L^1=L$, $L^2=\langle x_3,\ldots ,x_7\rangle $, $L^3=\langle x_4,\ldots ,x_7\rangle $, $L^4=\langle x_6,x_7\rangle $, $L^5=\langle x_7\rangle $,  and $L^6=0$, but where the center has dimension $2$, namely
$Z(L)=\langle x_5, x_7\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks. I will need to think a bit to see this. Are the missing brackets assumed to be $0$, or does this in fact follow from the written ones? I also need to think a bit about why it is indecomposable (which seems mainly to need me to write things up).

Comment: Right, the missing brackets are zero; the algebra is number $7.27$ in Magnin's classification of indecomposable complex nilpotent Lie algebras of dimension $7$.